# iOS7 shifts entire safari view

Tags: extjs, ios7, safari

I'm seeing some odd behaviour in iOS7 with my app that only demonstrates in iOS7.

When the keyboard comes up from the bottom it pushes the screen up to focus the input box. After the keyboard is dismissed a grey space remains where it was, leaving the rest of the window pushed up. Images below will demonstrate what I'm saying.

I'm using Sencha on this webapp.

While the images show the split keyboard, this occurs for both split and non-split keyboards

[image: Image 1. Screen at rest]
[image: Image 2. Pop keyboard up]
[image: Image3. Keyboard remains]

I can swipe down in the grey space to bring the rest of the view back onto the screen, but that isn't a solution.

What is the cause of this behavior and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a slightly modified email that I sent out describing the cause of this:

After seeking an answer for our keyboard issue but coming up empty handed I think I figured out what is going on. It seems to be related to a bug in iOS 7.

Take a look at the attached ‘normal_behaviour.jpg’ file. This shows what the split keyboard looks like from iOS 6 to iOS 8. The input field I had selected on the Apple website was near the top of the page. When I touched it the web page slid up very slightly to ensure that the input field was still visible.

In the attached ‘unwated_behaviour.jpg’ file I found an input field close to the bottom of the screen and selected it. On both iOS 6 and iOS 8 the keyboard covers the input filed, however on iOS 7 the entire webpage is slid up so you can see the input field, which is great from a user friendliness perspective, but then when the keyboard is dismissed that grey area where the keyboard was remains, and the rest of the webpage does not slide back into place.

Also of note is that once you select an input field near the bottom of the page with a split keyboard you are able to slide beyond the end of a webpage in any other website you bring up within the same Safari session. You can see a few examples of it in ‘buggy_behaviour_other_pages.jpg’.

Of course with our app we are really using a Safari webview to display pages so we are vulnerable to the same issue when using the Split keyboard. The issue does not present itself with the full keyboard.

**Unwanted behaviour.jpg**
[image: Unwanted behaviour.jpg]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Normal behaviour**
[image: Normal behaviour]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Buggy behaviour other pages
[image: Buggy behaviour other pages]